# In Python, is 'foo = x or "default"' correct?

Tags: python

In javascript, `foo = x || "default"` is often coded. If `x = null`, `foo = "default"`.

In python, is `foo = x or "default"` correct?

Comment: If x is `0` or any "falsy" value `foo` will be set to "default".

Comment: Just to add this: Often Python programmers use the `x and y or z` in Python to express "return `y` if `x` is true else return `z`. Since Python 2.5. there is the inline if to replace that so-called boolean shortcut, since in some situations it might not give the wanted results.

Comment: Define "correct". Do you mean that it's not a `SyntaxError`? That its result is the same a different statement that you didn't provide in the question making it useless? Or what? In any case questions should be researched before being asked.

Answer (score 2):

Your code as written will produce the behavior you describe, but I would suggest the following, which is the [Python canonical form of a ternary expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

```
>>> x = None
>>> foo = x if x else 'default'
>>> foo
'default'
```

If you are familiar with C++, you can read the above as if it were the below ternary expression

```
foo = x ? x : "default";
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it works. From [documentation -](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is `false`, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if x is `true`, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> (Note that neither `and` nor `or` restrict the value and type they return to `False` and `True`, but rather return the last evaluated argument. This is sometimes useful, e.g., **if `s` is a string that should be replaced by a default value if it is empty, the expression `s or 'foo'` yields the desired value.**

(Emphasis mine)

Please note when you do -

```
foo = x or "default"
```

if `x` is `None` or empty string, in both cases `"default"` would be the return value of the expression  - `x or "default"` .

Answer (score 2):

It is 'correct'/valid code (as long as `x` is defined), but bear in mind that `foo` will be set to `"default"` for any falsy value such as `0`, `""`, `[]` or `{}`.

If you only want to use the default value if `x` is not `None`, you can use:
`foo = x if x is not None else "default"`

This is demonstrated below.

```
x = 0
print(x if x is not None else "default")  # prints 0
print(x or "default")  # prints default
```

If you are defining a function, you will probably just want to use default parameters.

Again, demonstrated below:

```
def myfunc(x="default"):
    print(x)

myfunc()  # prints default
myfunc("custom value")  # prints custom value
```

Answer (score 1):

If by "correct", you mean "does it work?", then yes, it is correct. It works fine and will work as you expect it to. Note, however, that if `x` is something like `False`, `0`, `None`, or `""`, `foo` will also be set to `default` due to the way boolean logic works in Python.

If by "correct", you mean "is it correct conventions?", then yes, I would also say it is correct. This is a common pattern that I have seen many developers use throughout several projects. It is also given as an example in the Python documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine if `x` is already defined, else you will get an error.

**Correct usage:**

```
 >>> x= None
 >>> foo = x or "default"
 >>> foo
 'default'
```

**Error case :**

```
>>> foo = x or "default"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    foo = x or "default"
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```